# How can I get better google indexing results?

Tags: seo, google-search, pagerank

I have just launched a new domain, www.nextlevelsmf.com and it's not showing for some keywords I would like it to. Can anyone give me some advice to help it rank better please?

I'd like it to show on the first 2 pages for:
Managed SMF hosting
SMF host/hosting
Managed SMF host

At the moment it's only really there for "next level SMF" searches. The other results for those keywords aren't even real results - many of those hosts do not offer managed hosting for SMF, or even SMF specific hosting.

Any advice would be appreciated :).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, with no programming aspect.

Comment: SEO IS programming, I don't know what more I can add to the source to make it rank better or anything.

Comment: Search engines don't see your source, they see the output. You'd be on-topic here if there was something you wanted your website to do for SEO, but couldn't figure out how to code it. That doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: Then you misunderstand my question. I've added meta tags and keywords and it's not made a difference. I want to know what else I can add or do to help.

Comment: You might have a programming question if you were asking about a programming problem. Right now, you're trying to figure out what it is you need to change on your website. Until you've figured that out, you don't have a programming question, because you don't know what it is you need to code.

Comment: We obviously define programming problems differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt see any mention of "Managed SMF hosting" on your pages, so why would you hope to rank for it ?

http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.co.uk/en/uk/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

Comment: It's in my meta tags and description. Thanks for the guide, I will go over that. I thought it mainly looked at the meta info when deciding. Thank you!!

Comment: You need it in actual content that people can see, meta tags and descriptions arent used for rankings.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!! For this help, I am completely new to SEO and you've helped me so much I actually reached my goal!! I went from page never to page 2 in a couple of days since I made some changes from the guide and I'm just really really so appreciative of your help!! I'm going to spend some more time going through the whole thing to fine tune it all, but so far the pages are displaying much nicer, in a better order in searches and definitely more appropriately. THANK YOU!!!!!